# camelCase to kebab-case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a kebabize function which converts camelCase to kebab-case. I am sharing my code. Can it be more optimized? I know this problem can be solved using regex. But, I want to do it without using regex.

```
const kebabize = str => {

    let subs = []
    let char = ''
    let j = 0

    for( let i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {

        char = str[i]

        if(str[i] === char.toUpperCase()) {
            subs.push(str.slice(j, i))
            j = i
        }

        if(i == str.length - 1) {
            subs.push(str.slice(j, str.length))
        }
    }

    return subs.map(el => (el.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + el.substr(1, el.length))).join('-')
}

kebabize('myNameIsStack')
```

Comment: Instead of optimizing your code, I really would advice you to use a library for this kind of util functions. For instance, use the [_.kebabCase](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#kebabCase) function from Lodash!

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Just improving my logical skills. That's why not using regex. I know this approach is cleaner and optimized.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```js
const kebabize = str => {
   return str.split('').map((letter, idx) => {
     return letter.toUpperCase() === letter
      ? `${idx !== 0 ? '-' : ''}${letter.toLowerCase()}`
      : letter;
   }).join('');
}

console.log(kebabize('myNameIsStack'));
console.log(kebabize('MyNameIsStack'));
```

You can just check every letter is if upperCase or not and replace it.

Comment: This will work only if input string is camelCase, not UpperCamelCase

Comment: @VinayMahamuni UpperCamelCase is PascalCase FYI, it's not the same.

Comment: `str.split("")` gives unexpected results with unicode symbols made up of multiple parts. Use `[...str]` or `Array.from(str)`.

Answer (score 51):

I have a one-liner similar to Marc's but with a simpler Regular Expression and ~20% faster according my benchmark (Chrome 89).

```js
const kebabize = (str) => str.replace(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]/g, ($, ofs) => (ofs ? "-" : "") + $.toLowerCase())

const words = ['StackOverflow', 'camelCase', 'alllowercase', 'ALLCAPITALLETTERS', 'CustomXMLParser', 'APIFinder', 'JSONResponseData', 'Person20Address', 'UserAPI20Endpoint'];

console.log(words.map(kebabize));
```

`[A-Z]+(?![a-z])` matches any consecutive capital letters, excluding any capitals followed by a lowercase (signifying the next word). Adding `|[A-Z]` then includes any single capital letters. It *must* be after the consecutive capital expression, otherwise the expression will match all capital letters individually and never match consecutives.

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) can take a replacer function. Here, it returns the lowercased matched capital(s) for each word, after prefixing a hyphen when the match offset is truthy (not zero - not the first character of the string).

I suspect Marc's solution is less performant than mine because by using replace to insert hyphens and lowercasing the whole string afterwards, it must iterate over the string more than once, and its expression also has more complex look aheads/behind constructs.

[Benchmark](https://jsbench.me/81knvtkfj2/1)

Comment: Not sure if anyone else expects this but, `-F` will turn into `--f`.

Answer (score 17):

### RegEx is faster!

Unlike what you might think, the RegEx way of doing this is actually significantly faster! See [benchmark](https://perf.link/#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%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).

The function below supports converting both `camelCase` and `PascalCase` into `kebab-case`:

```js
function toKebabCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1-$2").toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: This fails with fully capitalized words. `JSONResponseData` would return `jsonresponse-data` instead of `json-response-data`. I suppose it could be a stylistic choice, but it's not what I think most people would expect and it will cause issues if they're not aware.

Comment: @ABabin, but wouldn't be correct `jsonRespondeData` instead of `JSONResponseData`?

Comment: @NNL993 There is no "correct" standard. Some people capitalize acronyms in `camelCase` - sometimes up to a certain length or selectively or all the time. The other solutions here handle those cases without significantly more overhead.

Answer (score 11):

**Here is my solution:**

Works with camelCase and PascalCase:

```js
let words = ['StackOverflow', 'camelCase', 'alllowercase', 'ALLCAPITALLETTERS', 'CustomXMLParser', 'APIFinder', 'JSONResponseData', 'Person20Address', 'UserAPI20Endpoint'];

let result = words.map(w => w.replace(/((?<=[a-z\d])[A-Z]|(?<=[A-Z\d])[A-Z](?=[a-z]))/g, '-$1').toLowerCase());

console.log(result);

/*

Returns:
[
  "stack-overflow",
  "camel-case",
  "alllowercase",
  "allcapitalletters",
  "custom-xml-parser",
  "api-finder",
  "json-response-data",
  "person20-address",
  "user-api20-endpoint"
]

*/
```

**Explanation:**

1. Match any of the following regular expressions:

- Find any capital letter, that is immediately preceeded by a small letter or a number, or
- Find any capital letter, that is immediately preceeded by a capital letter or a number, that is immediately followed by a small letter

2. Replace the captured position with a dash ('-') followed by the captured capital letter
3. Finally, convert the whole string to lowercase.

Comment: Doesn't work on safari.

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like this.

```js
function kebabize(string) {
  // uppercase after a non-uppercase or uppercase before non-uppercase
  const upper = /(?<!\p{Uppercase_Letter})\p{Uppercase_Letter}|\p{Uppercase_Letter}(?!\p{Uppercase_Letter})/gu;
  return string.replace(upper, "-$&").replace(/^-/, "").toLowerCase();
}


const strings = ["myNameIsStack", "HTTPRequestData", "DataX", "Foo6HelloWorld9Bar", "Áb"];
const result  = strings.map(kebabize);

console.log(result);
```

This snippet replaces all uppercase characters before or after a non-uppercase character with `-` followed by the uppercase. It then removes the `-` at the start of the string (if there is any) and downcases the whole string.

Comment: be careful about this solution, Safari will fail because, Safari does not support the negative lookbehind yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for older browsers:

```js
var str = 'someExampleString'
var i

function camelToKebab() {
  var __str = arguments[0]
  var __result = ''

  for (i = 0; i < __str.length; i++) {
    var x = __str[i]

    if(x === x.toUpperCase()) {
      __result += '-' + x.toLowerCase()
    } else {
      __result += x
    }
  }

  return __result
}

console.log(str, '->', camelToKebab(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
let resultDiv = document.querySelector(".result");

let camelCase = "thisIsCamelCase";
let kebabCase;
kebabCase = camelCase.split('').map(el=> {
  const charCode = el.charCodeAt(0);
  if(charCode>=65 && charCode<=90){
    return "-" + el.toLowerCase() 
  }else{
    return el;
  }
})

return(kebabCase.join(''))
```

Comment: How about using the index provided by the map() and removing charCode?
```
kebabCase = camelCase.split('').map((el,index)=> {
  if(camelCase.charCodeAt(index)>=65 && camelCase.charCodeAt(index)<=90){
    return "-" + el.toLowerCase() 
  }else{
    return el;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation does a good job, but there are a few ways to make it more efficient or concise. Here is a slightly optimized version of your function, keeping the core logic but streamlining it a bit:

```html
const kebabize = str => {
    let result = ''; // Use a single string to build the result

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let char = str[i];
        
        // Check if the character is uppercase
        if (char === char.toUpperCase() && i !== 0) { // Add a dash before uppercase letters, except the first character
            result += '-';
        }
        
        result += char.toLowerCase(); // Add the lowercase version of the current character to the result
    }

    return result;
};

console.log(kebabize('myNameIsStack')); // Outputs: my-name-is-stack
```