# Convert a CSSStyleDeclaration object to a Style Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can you create a CSS Style Sheet Rule from a CSSStyleDeclaration object?

The docs for inserting a new Style Sheet rule require the selector and declaration to be declared as a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

```js
myStyle.insertRule('p { font-weight: bold, color:red }');
```

But what if you already have it as a `CSSStyleDeclaration` like object?

```js
{
 fontWeight:'bold',
 color:red
}
```

You could loop the object, set each prop on a tmp `element.style` and then grab its css text...

```js
const myStyle = {
    fontWeight:'bolder', 
    color:'red',
}; 

const tmpStyleEl = document.createElement('style');


for( const prop in myStyle ) {  
    tmpStyleEl.style[prop] = myStyle[prop];
};

// this converts it to a valid css string format
const ruleStr = tmpStyleEl.style.cssText;

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.sheet.insertRule(`p { ${ruleStr} }`);

document.body.append(style);
```

But that feels overkill!

**Some Background**

We have user defined styles/themes (saved as CSSStyleDeclarations at the moment), and then we have user generated HTML (simple collection of `<p>` and `<h1>` tags generated by Quill).

We then want to generate a Stylesheet so all the nested `<p>` and `<h1>` tags can pick up on the style....

Maybe we store the style declarations as an actual CSS Style Sheet string?  We could then create the sheet as an external `.css` file - but then to populate the model data for the UI controls to edit the theme, we would have to do some reverse process to the above anyway....

Answer (score 0):

This is probably unsafe and you should stick to using elements, but I suppose you could use `Object.entries` and create a string from that:

```js
const myStyle = {
    fontWeight:'bolder', 
    color:'red',
};

// Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116039/camelcase-to-kebab-case
const kebabify = (str) => str.replace(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]/g, ($, ofs) => (ofs ? "-" : "") + $.toLowerCase())

const style = document.createElement('style');

// get entries as key-value pairs
// format with a colon
// join rules with semicolons
style.sheet.insertRule(`p { ${
    Object.entries(myStyle)
        .map(([key, value]) => `${kebabify(key)}: ${value}`)
        .join("; ")
} }`);

document.body.append(style);
```