# Spring boot - converting to and from canonical form of property names maintaining nesting?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, canonicalization

I have a bunch of Spring configuration files in various formats from various projects. I am doing some analytics on the combined merged results of the properties files.

So I would like to parse out the hierarchy of each file (yaml, json and properties files).

But the trick is I need to convert each property key into canonical form before I store it into the data structure. because of this stuff https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Canonical-properties

Namely:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=mysql
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=mysql
spring.JPA.database_platform=mysql
```

Each of these properties is the exact same.

So the tricky part here is that each property key needs to be converted to canonical form before doing any sort of comparison.

Is there a Spring-friendly-way to convert keys to and from the canonical form?

Examples:

`databasePlatform` -> `database-platform`
`dataBasePlatform` -> `data-base-platform`

Because I have found random canonical string snippets on the internet and none of them seem to work quite like Spring's does.

Any advise how to proceed here is welcome thanks.

Here is what I've found so far:

```
public String convertToCanonicalForm(String key) {
  return key.replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Upper}+|\\d+)", "$1-$2").toLowerCase();
}
```

but I'm not sure about some of the edge cases. How do you handle `abc123` is it `abc-123` or `abc123` ? Or what about `a123` is that `a-123` or just `a123`? Or what about `A123` is that `a-123` or `a123`? etc.

UPDATE: I found a better function here, but not sure if this is adequate:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70226943/1174024

```
    public String convertToCanonicalForm(String key) {
        return key.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").toLowerCase();
    }
```