# How to select only one input

Tags: javascript, html

please tell me how to make an analogue of radio inputs with a checkbox? To be able to select only one input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory">
```

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="subcategory"]');

inputs.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.checked = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Is there a feature of radios that you don't want?

Comment: Customize checkboxes: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make checkboxes "feel like" radio groups, you will need to do a few things.

- Add a data attribute to the checkboxes to enable single-checked mode i.e. `data-check-radio`
- Ensure that the input names end in square brackets i.e. `name="subcategory[]"`
- Assign unique values to each input

I have created a helper function below that can be re-used:

```js
// Reusable function
function CheckRadioHelper(dataProperty) {
  dataProperty = dataProperty || 'checkRadio';
  window.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    if (
      event.target.tagName === 'INPUT' &&
      event.target.type === 'checkbox' &&
      (
        (
          event.target.dataset &&
          event.target.dataset.hasOwnProperty(dataProperty)
        ) ||
        event.target.hasAttribute(`data-${toKebabCase(dataProperty)}`)
      )
    ) {
      document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${event.target.name}"]`)
        .forEach(function(sibling) {
          if (sibling.value !== event.target.value) {
            sibling.checked = false;
          }
        });
    }
  });
}

CheckRadioHelper(); // Now, call it

// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67243723/1762224
function toKebabCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]/g, function(match, offset) {
    return (offset ? '-' : '') + match.toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="1" />
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="2" />
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="3" />
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="4" />
```

**Note:** I added a `toKebabCase` method in case `Element.prototype.dataset` does not exist. It falls back to using an attribute check.

Here is an ES6 version that is simplified:

```js
// Reusable function
const CheckRadioHelper = (dataProperty = 'checkRadio') => {
  window.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
    if (
      target.tagName === 'INPUT' &&
      target.type === 'checkbox' &&
      target.dataset.hasOwnProperty(dataProperty)
    ) {
      document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${target.name}"]`)
        .forEach((sibling) => {
          if (sibling.value !== target.value) {
            sibling.checked = false;
          }
        });
    }
  });
}

CheckRadioHelper(); // Now, call it
```

```html
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="1" />
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="2" />
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="3" />
<input data-check-radio type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" value="4" />
```